# handle ArrayIndexBoundsOfException when the String value is dynamic

Tags: java

I have a dynamic string value coming which i need to split and assign to other fields as shown in the below sample code.

```
public class TestDataType {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
        String useCaseId;
        String partner;
        String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782"; //dynamic string
        // String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782-Alex";
        // String s = "Annie--83B782-";
        final String[] tokens = s.split("-");
        firstName = tokens[0];
        lastName = tokens[1];
        useCaseId = tokens[2];
        partner = tokens[3];
        System.out.println("firstName " + firstName);
        System.out.println("lastName " + lastName);
        System.out.println("useCaseId " + useCaseId);
        System.out.println("partner " + partner);
    }
}
```

The above code is throwing the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
```

As i dont have the tokens[3] in the String when used the split (`String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782";`) ,it is throwing the above exception, how can i handle in the program all the possible scenarios as when i have tokens[3] assign the value else make it blank.. Similarly how can i handle the when `String s = "Annie--83B782-` .

Comment: *"how can i handle [this]?"* Using `if` statements that check the size of the array, i.e. `tokens.length`. --- If find it curious that you know the `split()` method, but don't know about `if` statements and/or array size.

Comment: @Andreas - I know the array size, my intension was to know the best approach to resolve when this situation occurs.

Comment: Regarding to your last problem on handling case like `String s = "Annie--83B782-`, it should be fine because it will still split and leave the respective index empty string (not null).

Answer (score 5):

This is a good time to use switch statements. I suggest you Google them to read more as they can be very helpful in situations like this. Here's your code:

```
String firstName = "";
String lastName = "";
String useCaseId = "";
String partner = "";
String s = "Annie-Marie-83B782";
final String[] tokens = s.split("-");


switch (tokens.length) {
case 4:
    partner = tokens[3];
case 3:
    useCaseId = tokens[2];
case 2:
    lastName = tokens[1];           
case 1:
    firstName = tokens[0];
    break;
default:
    System.err.println("Invalid input");
    return;
}

System.out.println("firstName " + firstName);
System.out.println("lastName " + lastName);
System.out.println("useCaseId " + useCaseId);
System.out.println("partner " + partner);
```

Comment: Is it possible using for-each loop by any chance @Tacodude7729

Comment: @user222 Not with 4 different local variables.

Comment: @user222 I don't think a for-each loop would be good here. You need to keep track of what index your looking at so you know what variable to assign the value to. A normal for loop could be good but even than you would need a switch statement in the for loop to determine which variable to store the value in. My solution is good because it's easily expandable, I don't think for loops are necessary.